# Oracle 11g installation on Remote Server(OS:Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, oracle

Please let me clear steps to install oracle 11g from local linux(or windows) machine to remote server( OS : Ubuntu).

When I try to run the runInstaller command,its not working from windows local machine.

Answer (score 2):

**

### THIS IS OFFERED WITHOUT WARRANTY - DEPENDING UPON YOUR OS VERSION THERE MIGHT BE SLIGHT CHANGES ~ Review before completing...

**

Begin by making sure that your system is up to date with all its packages:

SSH into the remove system (via putty or the client of your choosing)

then run

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade 
# reboot
```

Once the system has rebooted - you should be in working shape and up to date.

There are a number of packages required to install Oracle -so reconnect via ssh and then issue the following command

```
#apt-get install build-essential libaio1 gawk ksh libmotif3 alien libtool lsb-rpm
```

Next - you will need to make a few changes to the system configuration:

```
# cd 
# pwd 
/root
```

Add a few groups here:  oinstall, dba and nobody

```
# addgroup oinstall 
# addgroup dba
# addgroup nobody
usermod -g nobody nobody
```

Add the oracle user

```
# useradd -g oinstall -G dba -p password -d /home/oracle -s /bin/bash oracle   
# passwd oracle
```

Now give Oracle its own home directory

```
# mkdir /home/oracle 
# chown -R oracle:dba /home/oracle
```

Next - create the symbolic links

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk   
# ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm   
# ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename   
# mkdir /etc/rc.d   
# for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S ; do ln -s /etc/rc$i.d /etc/rc.d/rc$i.d ; done
```

Next - Create the ORACLE_BASE

```
# mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle   
# chown -R oracle:dba /u01
```

There are a number of parameters that need to be changed in the system configuration to ensure the system is ready to run the application -

First - change the size of shared memory in the /etc/sysctl.conf file

```
fs.file-max = 65535   
kernel.shmall = 2097152   
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648   
kernel.shmmni = 4096   
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128   
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535   
net.core.rmem_default = 1048576   
net.core.rmem_max = 1048576   
net.core.wmem_default = 262144   
net.core.wmem_max = 262144
```

Integrate the following into the /etc/security/limits.confce file:

```
oracle soft nproc 2047   
oracle hard nproc 16383   
oracle soft nofile 1023   
oracle hard nofile 65535
```

it will add the following to /etc/pam.d/login to validate parameters /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so   
session required pam_limits.so
```

RESTART THE SYSTEM @ THIS POINT BEFORE CONTINUING...

Now simply log into the system as the Oracle user via the login/password created in the previous steps above:

Now download and launch the Oracle runInstaller and follow the prompts

Once it is completed - it should make some changes to your /etc/profile - no worries as this should be done automagically.

Finally - add the following variables to the /etc/profile:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle   
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.X.Y/db_home1   
export ORACLE_OWNR=oracle   
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

You should now be complete :-)

If you are unsure how to use SSH -I would suggest contacting a SysADMIN to help. 
however - if you do a quick google search for putty.exe - you can download it and then run to begin.

Comment: Glenn,I don't have apt-get(apt packages),dpkg,startkde,gnome-session command.

Comment: So,I can't do any installation without these commands, and I tried installing oracle from my local windows machine at remote server.For that I needed VNC server for OUI ,I installed VNC server at my remote server,But I try to run that vnc server,it doesn;t work since it says startkde(or gnome-session),twm commands not found.

Comment: When I tried runnign runInstaller using ssh from my other local linux machine at remote ubunutu server,then I need X11 forwarding for that,I did that , tried again,it says,this error...... X connection to hostname:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).Please help me,Its very urgent.

Comment: Sameer I tested this locally - you may want to make sure you are using the correct repositories to install from.

Comment: No,I have downloaded packages under u01/app/oracle/database ,there is an runInstaller,which I tried running.Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Should "lsb-rpm" be "librpm-dev"?  Only think I could find like it.  Also, I don't have a limits.confce file, and can't find any info on such a file.  Is it okay to just create it with those values?